# Putting input into JavaScript Tables

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

I've been trying to create a table created by JavaScript. I finally found a way to create the table, but I lack the knowledge to put an input tag and a form into this table

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = "Replace this with other input";
cell2.innerHTML = "Replace this with input";
```

The style is irrelevant, I have all the code I need behind that

Answer (score 1):

The Solution:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

var input1=document.createElement('input');
input1.setAttribute('type','text');
input1.value='input1';

var input2=document.createElement('input');
input2.setAttribute('type','text');
input2.value='input2';


cell1.appendChild(input1)
cell2.appendChild(input2)
```

```html
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Comment: How do i set the method that it uses (e.g POST)